# Fastest way of reading audio files in Python

Tags: python, audio

I'm processing about 500,000 audio files, each about 10 seconds long. The bottleneck is reading the audio files. I'm currently using `pydub`, and have tried reading both as mp3 (original source) and wav (after ffmpeg conversion). Both are too slow, and would take more than 3 days!

Does anyone know if there's a faster method I can use to read these audio files? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[audiofile](https://pypi.org/project/audiofile/) is focused on reading speed is among the fastest libraries for Python, according to [this benchmark](https://audeering.github.io/audiofile/benchmark.html). The benchmark might not be independent, but it's not much biased either. It's a solid choice.

Assuming you have fast drive, you should use `audiofile` in tandem with `joblib` for parallel read (not `multiprocessing`). The number of jobs you can fire should depend on when the system becomes either I/O- (more likely) or CPU-bound.

If you'd like to stick to `ffmpeg`, consider parallel conversion with `GNU Parallel`:

```sh
OUTPUT_DIR="YOUR_DIRECTORY"
find . -name '*.mp3' -type f -print0 | parallel -0 ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 1 -i {} -filter:a loudnorm ${OUTPUT_DIR}/{.}.wav
```

Parameters:

- `-f s16le` - signed 16-bit little endian samples
- `-ar 48000` - sample rate 48kHz
- `-ac 1` - 1 channel (mono)
- `-i file.raw` - input file
- `-filter:a loudnorm` [EBU R128 loudness normalization](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#loudnorm)

Comment: I have SSD, so it should have reasonably good performance, although I haven't pushed it to it's limit enough to know for sure. That benchmark also shows me just how poor mp3 is compared to wav; but even converting between the two using `ffmepg` is taking forever.

Comment: @moinudin That's perfectly normal: `mp3` is a complex lossy compression algorithm, while with `wav` you simply read in bytes. You could consider parallel `ffmepg` and then reading WAVE, if for any reason that works better for you.

Comment: With audiofile + wav files + joblib, it's going significantly faster. Currently processing 4 files per second, while ffmpeg is also busy converting at the same time. There's a big variance though, which I'm guessing is due to disk IO.

Comment: I'm going to wait for ffmpeg to finish conversion and try again.

Comment: @moinudin I edited my answer to include parallel ffmpeg in case it could be handy to you. It's blazing fast.

Comment: That's what I'm running. It's fast, but has 500,000 files to get through. It's made it through about 20% of the files since I posted my last comment.